# c++ treat the address location as an integer

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I want to know if there is anyway that I can store the address location of a variable as an integer value.
For example, let's say that I have a number stored in some location in memory

```
int i= 20;
```

and we know that for example, the location of the variable i is 0x77C79AB2.
e.g.

```
int * ip = &i;
```

so we know that ip = 0x77C79AB2.

But at this point the variable ip is just a pointer. But let's say that I now want to store the address location 0x77C79AB2 into a variable of type int (NOT of type Pointer).

so, somehow I want to be able to make another variable of type (int) to actually store the number 0x77C79AB2 as a value not as a address location.

```
int a = 0x77C79AB2;
```

So, I could do whatever I want with the variable a. For example, I want to treat a as an integer and add a hex number 0x20 to it.

e.g.

```
int b = a + 0x20 =  0x77C79AB2 + 0x20 = 0x77C79AD2
```

Is this possible?
How could I make this assignment ?

Comment: It is better to use std::size_t to store memory addresses. int has sign and this is not good for memory addresses.

Comment: Additionally, on a 64 bit machine `int` will probably not be big enough to hold an address value.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Depends on the compiler. `int` is 64-bits on some compilers, and thus would have a large enough storage size.

Comment: A even better option is `std::uintptr_t`, an unsigned integer type guaranteed by standards to hold any address.

Answer (score 30):

Pointers are not integers. If you want to store a pointer value, you should almost always store it in a pointer object (variable). That's what pointer types are for.

You *can* convert a pointer value to an integer using a cast, either a C-style cast:

```
int foo;
int addr = (int)&foo;
```

or using a C++-style cast:

```
int foo;
int addr = reinterpret_cast<int>(&foo);
```

But this is rarely a useful thing to do, and it can lose information on systems where `int` happens to be smaller than a pointer.

C provides two typedefs `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` that are guaranteed to be able to hold a converted pointer value without loss of information. (If no integer types are wide enough for this, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` will not be defined). These are declared in the `<stdint.h>` header, or `<cstdint>` in C++:

```
#include <stdint.h>
// ...
int foo;
uintptr_t addr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&foo);
```

You can then perform integer arithmetic on the value -- but there's no guarantee that the result of any arithmetic is meaningful.

I suspect that you're trying to do something that doesn't make much sense. There are rare cases where it makes sense to convert a pointer value to an integer and even rarer cases where it makes sense to perform arithmetic on the result. Reading your question, I don't see any real indication that you actually need to do this. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It's likely that whatever you're trying to do, there's a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Why would you use `intptr_t` if you have `uintptr_t`? For relative addressing or something? Must `intptr_t` be a larger data size than the unsigned version since it cannot utilize its signed bit, thus its range is smaller?

Comment: @snowandotherjoys: Are you assuming that pointers are unsigned? Pointers had no signedness, and a signed integer might be the most natural representation on some systems. There's no reason to assume the sign bit can't be used.

Answer (score 5):

Q: Is there any way I can store the address location of a variable as an *integral* value.

A: Sure.  All you have to do is cast.

CAVEATS:

1) Just remember that sizeof(int) != sizeof (char *) on all platforms.  As mentioned above, use "size_t" whenever possible.

2) For C++, consider using reinterpret_cast<>:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 3):

The header `cstdint` defines a type `uintptr_t` which is an integer type large enough to hold a pointer. Cast your pointer type to it with reinterpret_cast. e.g:

```
#include <cstdint>

...

int i = 20;
uintptr_t ip = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already do things like adding an offset by just going back to array syntax: ip[0x20]. You can typecast between different types of pointers to change the offset "step size".